# What are the steps of making a fully undetectable piece of malware?

Tags: malware, antimalware

I've been recently taught how antiviruses work. I know that there is more to it but they basically have a list of known malware that they have encountered and every time they scan, they check if their database content matches the scanning files (heard this in an algorithm & data structures class).

Now my question is, *what are the steps and things to consider when an attacker wants to make a piece of malware look eligible?*

Should the malware be brand new so no-one has ever had an encounter with it, are there practices that take down the previous assumption?

Comment: did you mean to use the word *eligible*?

Comment: I removed your question about what skills are required, because it is a separate question (and too open-ended).

Comment: I think that you need to continue to do more reading about how antiviruses work. You have described the simplest (and oldest) form of virus detection and there are many (newer) methods used.